# Webpart (SharePoint) programming language

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

It's merely a tech question, but what language do I use t create a Webpart, that later I want to add on my SharePoint page? I just have to create a basic Webpart design and integrate it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint is an ASP.NET application and platform, thus any .NET (CLR) enabled language will do. However C# is "the" .NET language, thus I suggest you to use that.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms415817(v=office.14)

Answer (score 0):

@anabura,

There are several types of webpart. If you're developing webpart solution, that would be .net language.

- [Create a web part in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/sharepoint/walkthrough-creating-a-web-part-for-sharepoint?view=vs-2019)

SharePoint client-side web parts are controls that appear inside a SharePoint page and execute client-side in the browser. They're based on SPFx and implemented by Front-end language such as Jquery/React.

- [Build your first SharePoint client-side web part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

BR

Comment: Well, i can not post an image here, of what I need, but it look like the one in the link attached : https://redstapler.co/rpg-style-card-design-with-hover-effect-html-css-tutorial/ 

For this I belive I can use react/jquery -> then save the files with .dwp/.webpart extension. Right?

Comment: it should be possible. https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/blob/master/samples/react-mgtEvents/README.md   And  https://ravichandran.blog/2020/05/17/document-card-carousel-in-the-sharepoint-framework-spfx-web-part/